# `typeof this.x_axis` returns `function` but in the next line `Uncaught TypeError: this.x_axis is not a function`?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

This is D3JS codes from http://bl.ocks.org/simenbrekken/6634070. I want to adjust it, so I can add it programmatically.

```
this.x_axis = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([this.now - (this.limit - 2), this.now - this.duration])
  .range([0, this.width]);
this.y_axis = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([this.height, 0]);

console.log(typeof this.x_axis); // Return `function`.
console.log(typeof this.y_axis); // Return `function`.

this.line = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveBasis)
  .x(function (d, i) {
    console.log(typeof this.x_axis); // Return `undefined`?!?!?!
    return this.x_axis(this.now - (this.limit - 1 - i)*this.duration);
  })
  .y(function (d) {
    return this.y_axis(d);
  });
```

Comment: You're making the call from inside another function. Functions don't "inherit" their *this* from the calling scope, you have to set it (or let it default to window/undefined in non/strict mode). You could make it an arrow function (but that will limit browser compatibility). See [*How does the “this” keyword work?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: I have just made it into global vars instead and it is working. I am not sure on why the `this.x_axis` cannot be accessed there. Similar works in other programming language :/.

Comment: But javascript is not some "*other programming language*". ;-) You get a different *this* because each function has its own *this* based on the call (mostly), it's not inherited or adopted from an outer scope (except for arrow functions).

Comment: @notalentgeek there is a way of keeping the reference to the scale inside the line generator using objects as you are. However, you'll have to provide a minimum working version of your code for any solution to be tested.

Comment: @notalentgeek you can research about this keyword in Javascript here: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado, I have tested I feel like `this` does not work in D3 event listener. After animation ends, I called `.on("end", this.loop);` and the next `this.loop` called has all of my `this` variable set to undefined. I guess it is impossible to make object that has an event to call its own function will all values retained :/....

Comment: @notalentgeek One problem at a time: first we'll deal with the line generator. Please, provide your code (it can be a fiddle/plunker/codepen/whatever).

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado, https://pastebin.com/pHNM1Wcy at line 51 the 2nd time `this.loop` is called, it has all `this` variables set to undefined.

Comment: I can't do anything with a pastebin. Besides that, I said *one* problem at a time.

Comment: I solved my problem.